# Site not valid when creating SMS links

Tags: html, sms, uri, w3c-validation

I wanted to create SMS link for my mobile website.

Code looks like this:

```
<a href="sms:+000 000 0000">+000 000 0000</a>
```

It is working on smartphone devices but I would like my website to be valid when validating on validator.w3.org.

Validator gives me error like this:

> Line 51, Column 141: Bad value `sms:+000 000 0000` for attribute `href` on element `a`: Illegal character in scheme data: not a URL code point.

How to fix that?

Comment: Replace the spaces with `-`?

Comment: Removed the spaces, that seem to work. Thanks